# Joomla - remove unwanted css from within component

Tags: php, css, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm designing a custom component where I am utilising the tmpl=component ability to render the component only rather than displaying the default template.

How can I, **within the component** itself remove the unwanted css files from the sites head which are creating a styling conflict?

Comment: Can you add some code here? We need to be able to recreate the scenario in order to answer the question.

Comment: Added to the above comment: Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at joomla.stackexchange.com).

Comment: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/25065/12352

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that I am aware of:

1) get an instance of the document object and remove the CSS files :

```
<?php 
         //get the array containing all the script declarations
         $document = JFactory::getDocument(); 
         $headData = $document->getHeadData();
         $styles = $headData['styles'];

         //remove your script, i.e. mootools
         unset($styles['/media/system/css/acc.css']);

         $headData['styles'] = $styles;
         $document->setHeadData($headData);
?>
```

2) remove CSS files directly from your template *index.php*:

```
<?php unset($this->_styles['/media/system/css/acc.css']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

to unset unwanted js or css and to load whatever you want  you can use the excellent plugin https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/eorisis-jquery/